# Send event directly to server container via HTTP request instead of web container

Tags: google-tag-manager

After some experimenting, I noticed it is possible to send events directly to a server container via HTTP request instead of pushing to the data layer (which is connected to a web container). A big advantage of this setup is that the front-end doesn't need to load any GTM script. Yet, I have some doubts because I don't find much documentation about this setup. This setup also brings some challenges like implementing automatically collected events (e.g. page_view). Does anyone have experience with this setup or is able to tell me why I shouldn't be following this path?

Regards, Thomas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely not a best practice, although this is actually a technically more beneficial path since... A few things, actually:

1. Can make your tracking completely immune to adblockers.
2. Has the potential to protect from malicious analytics spam, also makes it way harder for third parties to spoil your data.
3. Doesn't surface your analytics stack and libraries to the public.
4. Is typically way lighter than the GTM lib.
5. You have a much better degree of control about what happens and have much more power over the tracking.

But this is only if you have the competency to develop it, which is a rarity, actually. Normally web-developers don't know analytics well enough to make it work well while analytics developers lack the technical knowledge. You now suddenly can't just hire a junior or mid implementation expert to help with the tracking. A lot of those who call themselves seniors wouldn't be able to maintain raw JS tracking libraries either.

As you've mentioned, you won't be able to rely on automatic tracking from GTM or gtag libraries. And not having automatic events is actually not the issue. The more important thing is manually collecting all dimensions, including the proper maintenance of client ids and session ids.

Once your front-end is ready, it's important to note that you don't want to expose your server-side GTM's endpoint. I mean, you can, but this would defeat the purpose significantly. You want to make a mirror on your backend that would reroute the events to the sGTM.

Finally, you may want to make up some kind of data encryption/protection/validation/authentication logic on your mirror for the data. You may consider it just because without surfacing the endpoints, you're now able to further conceal what you're doing thus avoiding much of potential data tampering. This won't make it impossible to look into what you're doing, of course, but it will make nearly impossible any casual interference.

In the end, people don't do it because this would effectively double the monetary cost of tracking since sufficient experts would charge approximately double from what regular analytics folks charge. However, the clarity of data will only grow about 10-20%. Such an exchange generally doesn't make business sense unless you're a huge corporation for which even enterprise analytics solutions like Adobe Analytics is not good enough. Amazon would probably be a good example.

Also, If you're already redefining users and sessions, you're not that far from using something like Segment for tracking and then ETLing all that into a data warehouse and use a proper BI tool for further analysis. And now is there still sense in having the sGTM at all if you can just stream your events to Segment realtime from your mirror, and then it can seamlessly re-integrate this data into GA, Firebase, AA, Snowflake, Facebook and tens if not hundreds more destinations, and this all server-side.

You want to know where to stop, and the best way to do it is by assessing the depth of the analysis/data science your company is conducting on the user behavioral data. And in 99% of cases, it's not deep enough to even consider sGTM.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, first of all thank you very much for your detailed answer. To do justice to your response, I don't want to respond too quickly. Instead, I’m able to analyze your arguments and provide a proper response hopefully tonight. And again, many many thanks for giving such a valuable answer. There aren’t many people that are able to talk about these subjects, let alone with your level of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

In response to @BNazaruk

So it's been a while now… I've been looking into the setup, because it’s just way too cool. I also took a deeper dive into CGTM to better understand the benefits of SGTM. And honestly, everything that has the probability to replace CGTM should be considered. My main reasons are;

Cybersecurity - Through injection it is possible to insert malicious software like keyloggers. The only thing that withholds this, are the login details to CGTM. These are, relatively speaking easy to get with targeted phishing.

Speed - A CGTM setup, with about 10 - 15 tags, means an avg performance loss of 40 points in Lighthouse.

Quality - Like you said; because browser restrictions like cookie policies and ad blockers that intercept/manipulate/block CGTM signals: On avg. 10-20% of the events are not registered in proper fashion.

Mistakes - Developing code outside a proper dev process, limits the insight into the impact of the code with possible errors or performance loss as a result.

So far I have created a standardized setup (container templates, measurement plans, libraries) for online marketers and developers to use. Within the setup, we maintain our own client and session ID’s. Developers are able to make optimal use of SGTM and increase productivity drastically. The only downside to the setup is that we still use CGTM to implement page_view and exceptions. Which is a shame, because I’m not far away from a full server-to-server setup. Companies are still too skeptical to fully commit to SGTM I guess. Though, my feeling says that in 5 years time, high-end apps won't use CGTM anymore.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, **[accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** that you found most helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33635216)

Comment: Cold but I can reason why.  Will do next time

Comment: Yeah, most SGTM implementations involve CGTM, which kinda defeats a lot of the purpose. Still, backend time is a lot more expensive than front-end. That is both, the developers time and CPU time (Network bandwidth too!). So migrating all the pageviews to backend would be painful. Also, you don't really need SGTM to solve the cookie problem. That cookie problem only affects the third party cookies and we have hacks to remedy that, replacing third party cookies with first-party via a simple backend mirror. Also, enterprises solve a lot of what SGTM does with CDP solutions.

Comment: Technically, yes, SGTM looks like a fun toy to play with. Realistically, it's almost as useless as mobile GTM when you factor in the cost. I've tried seducing a few clients into using it right when it was published, but now I realize that I just really wanted to play with it and it's really rarely worth it. I played with it locally.